# Authorization Header not sent through an HttpClient request

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, basic-authentication, dotnet-httpclient

#### Context

I want to make a simple API call with Basic authentication, using the HtppClient, in a Xamarin app.

#### Problem

I have been doing it with no problem for a while, but since a few days, it seems not to work anymore. No matter if I checkout previous commits or not. This request does work with Postman ofc, so I'm sure it comes from my code somewhere, and not the API.

I tried targeting both .Net Standard 2.0 or 2.1 and no matter what I do, API tells me I lack Authorization header. I even tried to display `myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` before the request (authorization is there and correct) and  `reponse.RequestMessage.Headers` after the request (Authorization is lacking, other headers are present).

#### Code Samples

Here is my initialization of the client :

```
HttpClient _clientNewApi = new HttpClient();
string authDataNewApi = string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
string authHeaderValueNewApi = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authDataNewApi));
_clientNewApi.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValueNewApi);
_clientNewApi.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

And here is the code making the request:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(recieved_uri);
// _clientNewApi.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization is well set
HttpResponseMessage json_response = await _clientNewApi.GetAsync(uri);
// json_response.RequestMessage.Headers does not contain Authorization Header
// json_response.StatusCode is Unauthorized, and the message sent back by the API is "No authentication credentials provided."
```

I've been desperately looking at my code and doing checkouts to no avail for hours guys, any clue rly appreciated :)

Comment: why dont you install something like fiddler to inspect the network request. Compare it to postman and you should see whas up.

Comment: I could do this to be 100% sure, but I'm already 99% sure that the Authorization field is lacking in the request sent by the HttpClient

Comment: From experience with HttpClient, that should be sending the Authorization header. So you'll need to show for definite, using Fiddler, that it isn't

Comment: Check json_response.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization

Comment: Your code looks well through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/rest#specifying-basic-authentication-in-a-web-request). Use some tools to debug the request and check your server side.

Comment: @ToddMenier as I stated, json_response.RequestMessage.Headers does not contain Authorization, and when I tried to call ToString on json_response.RequestMessage.Headers.Authorization, it threw an exception

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT, i'm afraid I don't have access to the server side :/ I have been trying to configure fiddler with a proxy for my phone, with no success untill now

Comment: Do you have other api? Try the authentication there to see if the problem still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late reply, but my problem came from the API that was sending redirect code (3XX).

Postman does the redirection without saying anything which is the reason I never saw it.

That code was handled automatically by the HttpClient as well but the Authorizations Headers were not transmitted to the redirected request (Security reason I guess). I had to disable to automatic redirection in order to handle it myself and pass the Headers to the second request.

Comment: This is the exact issue i ran into. Stopping the auto redirect from postman helped debug my issue!